# Can I change the content in another language website from admin backend

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, language

I want to ask if there is a possibility that I can change the content in another language website using admin back-end instead of developer back-end (code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it from the admin panel but there are some limitations for it that is you can change most of the content from the admin on the basis of **`website/store_views`** but you can't change all of them from the back-end.

Here I am listing the things that you can have in different languages by doing some changes from the back-end.

- **CMS page** -> You can create different pages with same URL & identifier but different store_view & can use it with the different content/language
- **CMS Block** -> You can have different blocks with different identifiers & different language/content & can call it to the phtml file or CMS pages on the basis of store view.
- **Product Name & other content** -> You can have same product with different name, description, short description, other custom attribute label & value (if they are allowed to have different value on the basis of store view)
- **Category Name & other content** -> You can have category name & other category attributes in different language on the basis of store view.
- **Email Templates** -> You can have email templates in different language based on the store_view.

Here I am listing the things that you can't have in different language from the admin-panel.

- The HTML elements of the front'end like button value, tabs value, default form field labels, etc.
- Almost entire cart & checkout page.
- Customer dashboard section.
- Product review section & field values.
- Those attributes which are not allowed to have different values on the basis of store_views.

Comment: thank you so much for this info!! now i have a clear picture of how magento 2 admin and developer backend works even more .

Comment: You are always welcome! Happy to help! :)